# proof of cauchy schwarz for inner product

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

[image]

could someone explain how to get from $\|x\|^2 - \beta \langle y,x\rangle - \bar{\beta}\langle x,y\rangle + |\beta|^2\|y\|^2$ to $\|x\|^2 - |\beta|^2\|y\|^2 $? I understand $$-\beta \langle y,x\rangle - \bar{\beta}\langle x,y\rangle = -2\mathcal{Re}(\overline{\beta}\langle x,y\rangle)$$ but I don't see how we conclude?

Comment: $-\beta <y,x> - \bar{\beta}<x,y> = -\mathcal{Re}(\beta<x,y>)$ should be $-\beta <y,x> - \bar{\beta}<x,y> = -2\mathcal{Re}(\beta<x,y>)$

Comment: yes sorry thats what I meant.

Comment: Actually, $$-\beta \langle y,x\rangle -\bar \beta \langle x,y\rangle =-2\text{Re}(\bar \beta \langle x,y \rangle)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter $\beta$ is presumed to be given by $\beta=\frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{||y||^2}$.

Noting that

$$-\beta \langle y,x\rangle -\bar \beta \langle x,y\rangle =-2\text{Re}(\bar \beta \langle x,y \rangle)$$

we see that

$$\begin{align}-\beta \langle y,x\rangle -\bar \beta \langle x,y\rangle&=-2\text{Re}(\overline{\beta} \langle x,y\rangle)\\\\
&=2\text{Re}\left(\frac{\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}}{||y||^2}\langle x,y\rangle\right)\\\\
&=-2\frac{|\langle x,y\rangle|^2}{||y||^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why did you not conjugate $\|y\|^2$?

Comment: $||y||^2=\langle y,y\rangle $ is purely real.

Comment: but $<a+bi,a+bi> = <a,a> -i<a,b> +i<b,a>+<b,b>$?

Comment: And that is also purely real since $$-i\langle a,b\rangle +i\langle b,a\rangle=-i (2i \text{Im}(\langle a,b\rangle))=2\text{Im}(\langle a,b\rangle)$$

Comment: cool, thanks for the help

Comment: You're quite welcome!  My pleasure. -Mark

Answer (score 0):

$$\|w\|^2=|x\|^2 - \beta <y,x> - \bar{\beta}\langle x,y\rangle + |\beta|^2\|y\|^2$$

$$=\|x\|^2-2\mathcal{Re}(\beta<x,y>)+ |\beta|^2\|y\|^2$$

Taking into account that $\beta:=\dfrac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|y\|^2}$:

$$\|w\|^2=\|x\|^2-2\mathcal{Re}\dfrac{|\langle x,y\rangle|^2}{\|y\|^2}+ \dfrac{| \langle x,y\rangle |^2}{\|y\|^4}\|y\|^2$$

Dropping the now useless $\mathcal{Re}$, (and simplifying the last term by $\|y\|^2$) this expression, indeed, reduces to

$$\|w\|^2=\|x\|^2-\dfrac{|\langle x,y\rangle |^2}{\|y\|^2}$$

Comment: This is not correct.  $\langle x,y\rangle ^2\ne |\langle x,y\rangle|^2$